# swagger ui is not showing any of rest resources

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am not able see any of the resource in swagger UI [ http://localhost:8088/swagger-ui.html ],

Followed example - 
https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-boot-swagger-example

Tried to see the base pacakage is correct or not , everything looks okay..
also change the code

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any().paths(PathSelectors.any())
```

Expectation is to display the resources as configured in SwaggerConfig.java

Comment: can you share the full configuration classes?

Comment: https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-boot-swagger-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/techprimers/springboot/swaggerexample/config/SwaggerConfig.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Try without regex.

```
@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
      return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).
                    select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build()
                    .apiInfo(metaInfo());
}
```

Comment: well, I tried this, no luck, can you tell me am i missing some basic setup for swagger ui launch ?

Comment: @UdayKiran It's working with your code in Github. Try this URL http://localhost:8088/swagger-ui.html#/

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with my browser or may be supporting files or not exits 
I posted screen at below location. as you said I changed the port 8080 , http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html .. no results
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2979#issuecomment-489267493

Comment: I have observed one thing in spring boot start up logs , i don't see swagger resources not downloaded or started. I think that's why I am not able to see the contents in swagger-ui page. 

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49944591/57170662-fab00700-6e2b-11e9-9857-7903465ac9ad.png

Comment: Just in case, try with the # at the URL end.

Comment: anyways I followed different approach to achieve this by adding spring mvc dependency.

Now I can see swagger-ui html is loaded in my spring boot startup
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/swagger-ui.html] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]